# .csv file seems to be converting number to date and hiding the original value

Tags: excel, pandas, csv, type-conversion

I have a .csv file with a location column. For building 8, room 103 I know that the value in the source database is 8-8103. When I open this file in Excel it converts this to 8/1/8103 and displays "Aug-03". That makes sense, I see why it converted it *(the Location column =YEAR(Equipment Location))*

[image]

What I CANNOT understand is when I read this same file into Pandas, use `open(file) file.read()` or just open it with Notepad++ the value that I see is "Aug-03".

[image]

How is it possible that the literal string value in a .csv appears in the function line of Excel, but shows as a wrongly converted string in programs that are reading it as text?

To add to this confusion, Excel is able to display 8/1/**8103** and 8/1/**8203** in the function bar and displays them both as "Aug-03". If the underlying string is Aug-03, how is it able to make that distinction?

I hope this makes sense to somebody,
Thanks.

Comment: I'd recommend posting a portion of your CSV (include the problematic column) and the full import command (not a picture of half of it).  If you still get a problem with the test code edit your post and include it so others can attempt to recreate.

Comment: Excel is ... terrible with CSVs. Notepad++ or Pandas show you the actual string. Excel tries to be helpful (and often fails). Your CSV file is fine, this is Excel being stupid.

Comment: To avoid this, never **Open** a csv file with excel. It is better to **Import** the file using either the legacy import wizard or Power Query.  When you do that, you can designate the `Equipment Location` column as being **Text**, and Excel will not try to convert it to a date.  If you **Open** it in Excel, and then **Save** it, the damage has already been done.

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld That is the correct answer! Thank you! I deleted my copy & downloaded again, then I used Power Query to import and the values are what I expected to see. Pandas is now complaining about encoding, but that's a separate issue.  
Thanks!